# Exploiting response splitting on a non redirect

Tags: response-splitting

I was messing around with cookie based CRLF locally and was wondering what the possible ramifications are for pages that don't have 302s (And just return 200). I could indeed break the page from loading by malforming the request, but no matter what I do I'm not able to return a response different than the page normally would. Is there any way to response split a non redirect page and forge a response?

Comment: Depends on how much you can inject. If you can inject body data you might try with meta-refresh to redirect the user or use meta-refresh with a data url. Or inject javascript an set location.href there etc.